# Play Framework 2.4 docker image run error

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4

I've setup a docker image for my app. Target platform is debian jessie.
Image is built without errors. Trouble occurs when I try to run it. I do it like this:

```
    sudo docker run appname -Dconfig.file=/tmp/application.conf -Dapplication.home=/root/targer/universal/stage
```

, supplying external config file and application.home env variable

Trouble is, that something is wrong with DI classes, which use custom bindings, i.e. I put this line in application.conf:

```
    play.modules.enabled += "me.example.inject.SetupInjectors"
```

In this class, which extends AbstractModule, i bind my implementation like:

```
    bind(Interface.class).to(InterfaceImplementation.class);
```

The error is

```
    Oops, cannot start the server. com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

  1) No implementation for core.notification.email.MailTemplateService was bound.
  while locating core.notification.email.MailTemplateService
    for parameter 2 at core.services.impl.user.service.UserServiceImpl.<init>(UserServiceImpl.java:55)
  while locating core.services.impl.user.service.UserService
    for field at controllers.Application.userService(Application.java:34)
  while locating controllers.Application
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:108)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
```

And 46 times it repeats same error for all custom binded components. Needless to say, activator run works like a charm. It appears so, that my play.modules.enabled setting is somehow ignored during launch

Also, worth mentioning is that i have a library dependency on other Play project which is packaged as a library and stored on sonatype nexus server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was trivial. I've passed -Dconfig.file from host FS, which was an absurd. So, I've changed my start script as

```
sudo docker run -v /home/myapp/conf:/conf myapp-Dconfig.file=/conf/application.conf -Dapplication.home="/root/target/universal/stage"
```

mapping my local path to image's fs. And Play Framework used an application.conf from classpath (it was there, as i have a library dependency on another Play! project.

Comment: After 2 days struggling with this, your answer helped to direct me to the solution. Thanks!. Just one note, there is a space between myapp and -Dconfig...

Comment: @YoZH It's been 7 years since your answer. Is this still the way to solve the injection issue? I'm encountering the same issue, and thought it would've been fixed by now. But I can't find much on this.